# LifecycleOwner abc is attempting to register while current state is RESUMED. LifecycleOwners must call register before they are STARTED

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle

I tried finding a solution to this issue but only found Kotlin solutions, so I figured I might ask here.
My current setup is this (in MainActivity.java):

```java
onCreate() {
// blabla
list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.serverbrowser);
        list1.setOnItemClickListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {

                        connVPN(position);

                    }
                }
        );
}

void connVPN(int position){
 // Do some server connection stuff
}
```

My exact issue is this:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleOwner com.dev.app.MainActivity@6afc93f is attempting to register while current state is RESUMED. LifecycleOwners must call register before they are STARTED.`

So, what should I do? I tried putting the code into a different class to no avail, also tried putting just the handling code inside another class to select it in the activity.xml file (which would be my favourite way of doing this), but that didn't work either.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your `connVPN` method calling `registerForActivityResult`? Did you [read the guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) that specifically mentions that you need to register ahead of time, just like the error message says you need to do?

Comment: I indeed read the error message and the guide, however I did not consider it applicable for my use case since I have no Intent but just need to call a function, without opening anything. So when implementing it, I get an ActivityNotFoundException which I cannot fix because it would break my code beyond fixing, at least from what I know right now.